# Unable to drag the horizontal scrollbar from right to left in Safari on Mac

Tags: css, macos, safari

I want to create a simple CSS that produces a horizontally scrolling scrollbar that flows from right to left, but in Safari, it is not possible to grab the scrollbar and move it.

```
overflow-x: scroll;
direction: rtl;
```

Is it possible that this is a kind of bug if it works in other browsers but the scrollbar cannot be operated in Safari?

I also considered using Webkit, but if it is a unique behavior of Safari, I am thinking of leaving it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal scrolling works fine in both Chrome and Safari.

```css
#d1, #d2 {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#d1 {
  background-color: green;
}

#d2 {
  background-color: blue;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sagittis mauris convallis ultricies vulputate. Suspendisse dignissim massa id lorem consequat semper. Maecenas consectetur libero tellus, in hendrerit est lobortis ac. Sed sit amet ipsum massa. Phasellus efficitur in arcu at tincidunt. Vestibulum egestas aliquet elit, ac maximus mauris commodo ut. Ut scelerisque ligula non consectetur molestie.
</div>
<div id="d2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sagittis mauris convallis ultricies vulputate. Suspendisse dignissim massa id lorem consequat semper. Maecenas consectetur libero tellus, in hendrerit est lobortis ac. Sed sit amet ipsum massa. Phasellus efficitur in arcu at tincidunt. Vestibulum egestas aliquet elit, ac maximus mauris commodo ut. Ut scelerisque ligula non consectetur molestie.
</div>
```